# Androidのdatabindingでincludeタグのlayoutを切り替える方法

Tags: android

例えばこういう感じのことを実現したいです。
どうすればいいでしょうか？

```xml
// res/layouts/main.xml
<layout>
  <data>
    <variable
      name="editable"
      type="boolean" />
  </data>

  <FrameLayout>
    <include layout="@{editable ? @layout/editform : @layout/show}" /> <!-- ←コレは動きません、こういう感じのことを実現したいです -->
  </FrameLayout>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

xmlに記述するのではなく、プログラムから親viewを取得し、条件分岐してinflateする。

Comment: databining、ないしlayout.xml上で実現する方法を探しているので、この方法はなしでお願いします

Answer (score 0):

includeタグを適当なViewGroupでラップし、そのViewGroupのvisibilityをスイッチさせる。

```xml
// res/layouts/main.xml
<layout>
  <data>
    <variable
      name="editable"
      type="boolean" />
  </data>

  <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/rootLayout">
    <FrameLayout
      android:id="@+id/editform_layout"
      android:visibility="@{editable ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"      
      tools:visibility="View.VISIBLE">
      <include layout="@layout/editform" />
    </FrameLayout>
    <FrameLayout
      android:id="@+id/show_layout"
      android:visibility="@{editable ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE}"      
      tools:visibility="View.GONE">
      <include layout="@layout/show}" />
    </FrameLayout>
  </FrameLayout>
</layout>
```

---

私が試したところ、仮に親Layout(rootLayout)がConstraintLayoutだった場合、崩れてしまった。LinearLayoutやFrameLayoutであれば大丈夫だった。